# How to tell if a string contains valid Python code

Tags: python, syntax, python-3.x

If I have a string of Python code, how do I tell if it is valid, i.e., if entered at the Python prompt, it would raise a SyntaxError or not?  I thought that using `compiler.parse` would work, but apparently that module has been removed in Python 3.  Is there a way to do it that also works in Python 3.  Obviously, I don't want to execute the code, just check its syntax.

Comment: @goldenparrot Last time I checked, `gcc` did not have a Python frontend and static compilers in general sucked at doing dynamic languages, if they even tried.

Comment: @delnan waiting for gcc-python now

Comment: are you really only looking for syntax errors? or also logical errors( ie `g==5` without setting a value for g) as `g==5` will ast.parse even with no g anywhere

Comment: @JoranBeasley Given that such errors are impossible to detect in the general case, research-level hard in many other cases, and still pretty darn expensive to find in all but the most trivial cases, I hope not for his sake.

Comment: i think pylint would catch it (in most cases) ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yeah, because the example error you gave is trivial. PyLint and co. are okay, but won't catch much a quick glance won't see either. I'm not aware of any tool complaining about calls like `f(MyClass())` where `def f(x): return 1 + x` in another module, but not about `f(MyClassWith__radd__())`.

Comment: Only syntax errors. And it needs to be part of the standard library.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [`ast.parse`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.parse):

```
import ast
def is_valid_python(code):
   try:
       ast.parse(code)
   except SyntaxError:
       return False
   return True
```

```
>>> is_valid_python('1 // 2')
True
>>> is_valid_python('1 /// 2')
False
```

Comment: I edited out the bare except.  I will accept (no pun intended) this answer as soon as the site lets me.

Comment: Fails on bare `return`. Use @leoluk's answer instead.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler module is now a [built-in](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/functions.html#compile).

> ```
> compile(source, filename, mode[, flags[, dont_inherit]])
> ```
>
> Compile the source into a code or AST object. Code objects can be
>   executed by an exec statement or evaluated by a call to eval(). source
>   can either be a string or an AST object. Refer to the ast module
>   documentation for information on how to work with AST objects.

The AST parser is now a [seperate module](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/ast.html).

> ```
> ast.parse(expr, filename='<unknown>', mode='exec')
> ```
>
> Parse an expression into an AST node. Equivalent to `compile(expr, filename, mode, ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST)`.

Comment: `compile` existed before and is nowhere the full `compiler` module. `ast` is closer.

Comment: But `compile` wants filenames and such.  I just want to check a string, not read or write to any files.

Comment: Just pass something like `<string>` as filename. Full details in the linked docs.

Comment: Aside from that, the `compile` function has a few quirks (requires specific newline characters, and raises a TypeError out of friggin' nowhere when there are NUL bytes in the input) other options don't have.