# Python Conditions

Tags: python, wing-ide

I would like to test if a string is computable using the built in function "eval". I would like to make a condition in my definition. I want it to produce true if the string is computable using eval, and false if trying to "eval" the string produces and error. Any functions that would help me to do so? Thanks.

Example:

t="(8+(2-4)"

s="8+(2-4))"

eval(s) would produce 6

eval(t) would produce error

i want to be able to use these two conditions in my definition where I would be expecting either an integer or error from the eval expression

Comment: Maybe `try........ except`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to check the syntax before making a call to eval().  You can try [ast.parse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.parse), as mentioned in this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11854793/1046267).

(Example as given in that answer, for easier reference):

```
import ast
def is_valid_python(code):
   try:
       ast.parse(code)
   except SyntaxError:
       return False
   return True

>>> is_valid_python('1 // 2')
True
>>> is_valid_python('1 /// 2')
False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(string):
    try:
        return eval(string)
    except:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

My instinct says to write a try block:

```
def checkeval(foo):
    try:
        eval(foo)
    except:
        return False
    return True
```

Proof:

```
>>> checkeval('(8+(2-4)')
False
>>> checkeval('(8+(2-4))')
True
```