# Python - check syntax of function code in string

Tags: python, string, syntax-error

I am looking for code to check if a string representing a function header of a function is syntactically correct.

Here is my string example:

```
'''+'def __init__(self,{arg})'.format(arg = ','.join(i for i in someListOranArgPassedIn), )+''':
```

If this function was defined as

```
def __init__(self,,...a,,//b):
```

and goes against syntactic rules, what can I add to raise an exception?

Answer (score -1):

Using the function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11854793/2507539).

```
import ast
def is_valid_python(code):
    try:
        ast.parse(code)
    except SyntaxError:
        return False
    return True

test_args = lambda args: "def init(self, {arg}):\n\tpass".format(arg = ",".join(args))
print is_valid_python(test_args(["a", "b"]))
print is_valid_python(test_args(["", "...a", "", "//b"]))
```

Comment: Fails on bare `return`. I suggest you use `compile` instead of `ast.parse`.

Comment: @Veedrac, I don't follow. Why would a `return` be a parameter in a function?

Comment: `is_valid_python("return")` gives `True`; it should give `False`. Doing a full compile with `compile` catches this.