# How to check type of str that can be evaluated Python

Tags: python, types, eval

Is there a way to check the type of a string that is able to be evaluated?

Example:

```
y = 2
x = 2
z = "y + x"
eval(z)
```

So variable **z** can be evaluated. That's good, but is there so that when I call isinstance on z it'll return **function** instead of str.

Or if possible, can I check if something *can* be evaluated?

Comment: But what is `z`? It's a string... If you want a function, then just declare it to be.

Comment: Yes, it has to be because the assignment we're doing involves us to call a check on a string that can be evaluated.

Comment: `def can_we_execute(text): raise Exception("Don't try to run code from text in the first place")`

Comment: `try` and `except` the `eval` call, maybe.

Comment: depending on what you mean by "*can be evaluated*" [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11854793/1013719) shows how to check if a string is valid python code

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you want a string here?

```
y = 2
x = 2
z = lambda: y + x
print z()

if callable(z):
    print "z is a function"
```

Otherwise, the easiest way is to try running it:

```
z = "y + x"
try:
    eval(z)
    print "z was runnable (And we ran it)"
except Exception:
    print "Nope, z is not a string that we can run"
```

If you don't want to actually run it, you can pre-compile it:

```
z = 'x + y'
try:
    z = compile(z + '\n', '<expression for z>', 'eval')
except SyntaxError:
    raise Exception("Could not process z")

# later
eval(z)
```

Or if you really feel like being hacky (python 3):

```
z = 'x + y'
try:
    z_code = compile(z + '\n', '<expression for z>', 'eval')
    z = lambda: None
    z.__code__ = z_code  # swap out the contents of our empty function with some new code
except SyntaxError:
    raise Exception("Could not process z")

# later - it's now actually a function!
assert type(z) == types.FunctionType
z()
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution that comes to my mind to see if a string can be evaluated is:

```
def can_evaluate(string):
    try:
        eval(string)
        return True
    except SyntaxError:
        return False
```

However, this has the side effect of executing the evaluation if the string can be evaluated.

Comment: sort of? this wouldn't be a valid check on `z` because `x` and `y` may not be visible, in which case you'd get a `NameError`

Comment: @RyanHaining: Depends on the OPs definition of "evaluatable". Is `1 / 0` evaluatable, despite throwing an exception?

Comment: @Eric that's true.  so maybe OP means "parsable"?

Comment: @RyanHaining: that's correct, as Eric said, if by "can be avaluated" the OP means "sintactically correct" this is the right solution. If he/she means that it makes sense in the scope the string is defined, then this solution is not correct